# JSON vs Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json

How can I convert this to a javascript object??

JSON.parse() gives me unexpected json at line 0 and angular.fromJson doesnt do anything.

**Or put this inside an array. I need to know the length of customers and I need the javascript object**

```
$scope.customers = allKeysToUpperCase(response.data.items);
        console.log($scope.customers);
        console.log(JSON.parse($scope.customers)); // this gives me error
        console.log(angular.fromJson($scope.customers)); // this doesnt do anything
        console.log(angular.fromJson($scope.customers).length); // this gives undefined
```

$scope.customers gives me this json

```
{
  "0": {
    "ACCOUNT_ID": 1,
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 1,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Peter",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "IDENTITY_CARD_NUMBER": 2132142131,
    "TAX_IDENTIFICATION": 2892031231,
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal"
  },
  "1": {
    "ACCOUNT_ID": 1,
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 1,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Peter",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "IDENTITY_CARD_NUMBER": 2132142131,
    "TAX_IDENTIFICATION": 2892031231,
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have an object already. please test with `console.log(typeof $scope.customers)`. if `'object'`, then no parsing is necessary.

Comment: it is object. but then why `$scope.customers.length` gives me undefined??

Comment: right, it is an object, not an array with `length` property. you could convert to an array with `array = Object.assign([], $scope.customers);`, if the indices are starting from zero without holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with

```
console.log(typeof $scope.customers).
```

and getting `'object'`, then no parsing is necessary.

> it is object. but then why $scope.customers.length gives me undefined??

Right, it is an object, not an array with `length` property.

You could convert it to an array with

```
array = Object.assign([], $scope.customers);
```

if the indices are starting from zero without holes.

Comment: You could also do: ```Object.keys($scope.customers).length```

Answer (score 0):

All of this makes sense, and here is the explanation:

`$scope.customers` is a valid javascript object.

For any of the other calls to work, you would have to encode that object via `JSON.stringify($scope.customers)`

THEN make your calls like this for example:

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.customers)));`
`console.log(angular.fromJson(JSON.stringify($scope.customers)));`
`console.log(Object.keys(angular.fromJson(JSON.stringify($scope.customers))).length);`

The angular docs tells you that it expects a serialized JSON string [REFERENCE DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson).